# registration using sip.js and websockets in Node (wss or ws)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sip

I'm trying to register SIP agents using sip.js and Node to start load testing to my Kamailio

```
Node version v0.10.32


process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"
global.WebSocket = require('ws')
// SipJS Initialization
var SIP = require('./sip-0.6.0.js');

var Uaconfig = {
        traceSip: true,
        register: true,
        userAgentString: 'sipJS Test tool',
        uri: 'ramenlabs.io',
        wsServers: ['wss://ramenlabs.io:5063'],
        authorizationUser: 'gogasca',
        password: '********'
        //hackIpInContact: true
};

var userAgent = new SIP.UA(Uaconfig);
```

When I run I get an error:

```
Thu Oct 16 2014 03:40:53 GMT+0000 (UTC) | sip.transport | WebSocket connection error: Error: unexpected server response (400)
```

Because initial Websocket from Sip.js lacks **Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: sip** to indicate SIP Protocol.
If i use sample web page it works perfectly with same parameters, but not from my node command line.
How to force this?

In API js I do see the '**sip**' extra header but contains the **window.Websocket**

```
try {
      this.ws = new window.WebSocket(this.server.ws_uri, 'sip');
    }
    catch(e) {
       this.logger.log('Error connecting to WebSocket ' + this.server.ws_uri + ': ' + e);
       //return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set debug=3 in kamailio.cfg, restart and try again. Then look in syslog file (/var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages) for debug messages from Kamailio to see if you get a hint on why the connection is not accepted.

Comment: what tool do you use to stress test Kamailio for websockets?